# Kotlin Multiplatform Cocoapods integration issue

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform

So Im trying to build a project using kotlin multiplatform, I managed to integrate with database/ktor etc but the problem is when I need some dependency from cocoapods. I've seen that starting with kotlin 1.4 xcode is not required to build such a dependency (however even tho it was failing unless I installed xcode on my machine). But to the point, everytime I add a `pod` section inside `cocoapods` in `build.gradle.kts` my sync is failing with:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: /var/folders/6p/0kpnx2mj22589gthf1dddjwhtr2_tq/T/15810392041507337443.m:1:9: fatal error: module 'AFNetworking' not found
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.interop.indexer.UtilsKt.ensureNoCompileErrors(Utils.kt:152)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.interop.indexer.ModuleSupportKt.getModulesASTFiles(ModuleSupport.kt:68)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.interop.indexer.ModuleSupportKt.getModulesInfo(ModuleSupport.kt:14)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.interop.gen.jvm.MainKt.buildNativeLibrary(main.kt:506)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.interop.gen.jvm.MainKt.processCLib(main.kt:264)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.interop.gen.jvm.MainKt.interop(main.kt:74)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.utilities.InteropCompilerKt.invokeInterop(InteropCompiler.kt:45)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.utilities.MainKt.mainImpl(main.kt:19)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.utilities.MainKt.main(main.kt:41)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':example:cinteropAFNetworkingIos'.
> Process 'command '/Applications/Android Studio 4.2 Preview.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

When I launch podspec it is generated correctly, my build gradle files:
Top one:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.4.31"
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0-beta06"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-serialization:1.4.31"
        classpath "com.squareup.sqldelight:gradle-plugin:1.4.4"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
        maven { url "https://kotlin.bintray.com/kotlinx" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And the one with cocoapods:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.KotlinNativeTarget

plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    kotlin("plugin.serialization")
    kotlin("native.cocoapods")
    id("com.android.library")
    id("kotlin-android-extensions")
    id("com.squareup.sqldelight")
}

kotlin {
    android()

    val iOSTarget: (String, KotlinNativeTarget.() -> Unit) -> KotlinNativeTarget =
        if (System.getenv("SDK_NAME")?.startsWith("iphoneos") == true)
            ::iosArm64
        else
            ::iosX64

    iOSTarget("ios") {}
    version = "1.0.0"
    cocoapods {
        summary = "This is sample Summary"
        homepage = "Home URL"

        pod("AFNetworking")
        pod("FirebaseAnalytics")
    }

    val coroutinesVersion = "1.3.9-native-mt"
    val serializationVersion = "1.0.0-RC"
    val ktorVersion = "1.5.3"
    val sqlDelightVersion = "1.4.4"

    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$coroutinesVersion")
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-core:$serializationVersion")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-core:$ktorVersion")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-serialization:$ktorVersion")
                implementation("com.squareup.sqldelight:runtime:$sqlDelightVersion")
            }
        }
        val androidMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-android:$ktorVersion")
                implementation("com.squareup.sqldelight:android-driver:$sqlDelightVersion")
                implementation("com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.7.1")
            }
        }
        val iosMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-ios:$ktorVersion")
                implementation("com.squareup.sqldelight:native-driver:$sqlDelightVersion")
            }
        }
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion(29)
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion(24)
        targetSdkVersion(29)
    }
    sourceSets["main"].manifest.srcFile("src/androidMain/AndroidManifest.xml")
}
```

Maybe someone already found solution to this?

Answer (score 5):

Have you run `pod install`?

Gradle needs the source code to generate kotlin headers.

So after you add a new pod dependency to your gradle file, you need to run first sync, which will fail, but it'll update your `podspec` file. Then you need to run `pod install` to fetch the source code, and then run sync again.

Comment: I did, first I do `sync` if fails, `podspec` file is generated and dependencies are in there, then I run `pod install` from not from `shared` but from `iosApp` as only there is a `Podfile` and then sync fails again- maybe thats the problem? Should I have `Podfile` inside my shared code? within `shared` or `iosMain` ?

Comment: Podfile should be in your iOS app directory, that's correct. so when you run `pod install` the module you've mentioned in the gradle file gets installed? in the console you should see `Installing AFNetworking`, also you can check that you have `iosApp/Pods/AFNetworking` folder with the code after install

Comment: @user2141889 Could you provide a sample project with this problem? The code you've attached to the question looks good so far

Comment: It did say `Installing AFNetworking` and there is `AFNetworking` inside `iosApp/Pods` however still sync fails with `module not found`

Comment: Also I've created repo with this config, that wont work: https://github.com/alm3thz/kmm-cocoapods

Comment: after updating gradle plugin version to 7.0.0-alpha14 (as I'm using canary version of AS) and gradle to 7.0(which is a requirement of the latest canary version) the sync went fine on my machine. I'm not sure if that's the issue, but try to update AS to 4.2 RC 1, and gradle to 7.0, maybe this will work.

Comment: not, it won't. I'm on AS Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 Patch 2 and on gradle 7.0.2, yet I have the same problem.

Comment: Worked for me.

1. Remove the `*.podspec* file;

2. Run the `podspec` gradle task;

3. Sync the project;

4. Profit!